# Testing directive in Angular/Jasmine - 'expect' doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

Given this directive:

```
angular.module(moduleName).
directive("dir1", function() {
      return {
        restrict: "AE",        
        scope: {
            myvar: '='
        },
        templateUrl: "app/directives/dir1.html",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.myvar = "Hello";
        }
      }
});
```

With this template `dir1.html`:

```
<span class="myclass">{{myvar}}</span>
```

I'm trying to unit-test with:

```
fdescribe("dir1 Directive", function() {

    var scope,element;

    beforeEach(module(moduleName));
    beforeEach(module('app/directives/dir1.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache,$rootScope,$compile) {
        var formElement = angular.element('<div dir1></div>');
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = $compile(formElement)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));


    it("should have content", function() {
        expect(element.find('class')).toEqual('myclass');
        expect(element.find('span').text).toEqual('Hello');
    })

});
```

In the test I'm trying to retrieve the value of the class attribute and the content of the text in the span element, but I get:

```
Expected ({ length: 0, prevObject: ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1 }), 
  context: undefined, selector: 'class' }) to equal 'myclass'.
        test/directives/dir1.test.js:20:40
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
        Expected Function to equal 'Hello'.
        test/directives/dir1.test.js:21:44
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you expect `element.find('class')` to do?

Comment: I expected to retrieve the value of the class attribute

Comment: That isn't how element finders work, as you already appear to know given that you then use `element.find('span')`; it would find an element `<class></class>`. It seems your question is really *"how do I get the classes on an element?"* `.find('.myclass')` would find an element with that class.

Comment: Well, read the documentation of element.find(). That's not what it does. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the pointer, I made work the second expect with `expect(element.find('span').text()).toEqual('Hello');`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see that `find ('class')` is incorrect as class is an attribute and not an element, but `myclass` is the value I need to retrieve, not to find.

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to. An angular element has a `hasClass()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested, this is the solution (thanks to JB Nizet)

```
it("should have content", function() {
    var span = element.find('span');
    expect(span.hasClass('myclass')).toEqual(true);
    expect(span.text()).toEqual('Hello');
})
```